# Why is my physixs simulation whacky?

Tags: physics

My physics simulation won't properly simulate. I've tried changing collisions, checking if anything is touching, making sure its all big. If you know any fix I'll be happy to hear it

[image]

[image]

Edit: I kinda got annoyed and quit without saving, but i do know that for the barrels i was using the cylinder collision option, then for the pallets i was using the box option, and for the rack i was using the convex hul one. Ive tried different ones though and they all ended up going like this

Comment: Please [edit] your post and an image of the settings you are using for the objects.

Comment: @cegaton I edited it